# Kotlin visibility of nested members

Tags: kotlin

I have a class with a nested, private class. I have a `Builder`, standard Java builder pattern, that constructs instances of this class. I don't want anyone outside of my class to be able to see my hidden class.

In Java I could do this:

```
public class Example {
    private SneakyType doNotExposeThis;

    private Example(Builder builder) {
        // OK 'cause in Java you can access the private
        // members of a nested class
        doNotExposeThis = builder.doNotExposeThis;
    }

    private static class SneakyType {
        SneakyType(String x) {
            // stuff
        }
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private SneakyType doNotExposeThis;

        public void addFoo(String something) {
            doNotExposeThis = new SneakyType(something);
        }

        public Example build() { return new Example(this); }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same in Kotlin:

```
class Example(builder: Builder) {
    private lateinit var doNotExposeThis: SneakyType

    init {
        doNotExposeThis = builder.doNotExposeThis
    }

    class Builder {
        // If private or internal I can't access it in Example.init
        // and if public it gets exposed. 
        val doNotExposeThis: SneakyType


        fun addFoo(something: String) {
            // actual construction is quite a bit more complex
            doNotExposeThis = SneakyType(something)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for the sake of Java interop I want to keep my builder. I also want it because my object is complicated to construct and I want it to be immutable so I have a builder with lots of setters, adders, vals, etc. and then in `init` I construct a single immutable `Example`.

The only alternatives I see are:

1. Instead of have a `SneakyType` in my builder save all the info necessary to construct one and then construct it in `Example`. Works but adds a ton of complexity.
2. Give up on `Example` being immutable and allow the builder to call into it to set up a `Sneaky`
3. Expose the `Sneaky`

Is there no way to mimic the Java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two viable options:

1. Use the `internal` [visibility modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html):

   ```
   class Example private constructor(builder: Builder) {
       private val doNotExposeThis: SneakyType

       init {
           doNotExposeThis = builder.doNotExposeThis
       }

       internal class SneakyType(x: String)

       class Builder {
           internal lateinit var doNotExposeThis: SneakyType

           fun addFoo(something: String) {
               doNotExposeThis = SneakyType(something)
           }

           fun build(): Example {
               return Example(this)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This will make `SneakyType` only visible within your Kotlin compilation module.
2. Make `Example` independent of its builder (this is what I recommend):

   ```
   class Example private constructor(private val doNotExposeThis: SneakyType) {
       private class SneakyType(x: String)

       class Builder {
           private lateinit var doNotExposeThis: SneakyType

           fun addFoo(something: String) {
               doNotExposeThis = SneakyType(something)
           }

           fun build(): Example {
               return Example(doNotExposeThis)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I agree that the 2nd option is really nice. Unfortunately, for me, I don't think it works nicely since I actually have a more complex data structure that just involves some things like `SneakyType`. The 1st option is what I ended up doing. Gave an up-vote for the good options. Not marking "correct" just yet in hopes that somebody comes up with a better idea. Thanks!